# does importing excel file to postgresql append or overwrite

Tags: sql, postgresql

so i'm creating a posrgresql database the gets it's data from CSV file,
this CSV is the master data that collect all the data from different sheets and it gets updated every day,
my question is if i kept importing that same CSV file will the data be appended and will be duplicated or it will overwrite the existing data in the table with the new one.

Comment: That depends on how you are putting the data into the table.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: @GordonLinoff i really wish if you could explain?

Comment: What is the command you use to import the CSV file?

Comment: i don't use command, i use the import wizard in pgadmin

Comment: i'm new to this so if anyone can explain how to do it in command way or anyother way i would be appreciated

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html And as I remember there is no commands in PostgreSQL which implicitly deleting something, except when you specify `cascade` option.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what DML operation you use 
If you use insert into table , it will append 
If you use load into table then two cases can happen first , if you specify replace in the load it will delete the existing data and insert the new . Second,  if you specify load append it will not delete the existing data and will insert the new data